# Spark: Loop through JavaRDD Tuple - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to loop through an JavaRDD with a tuple however I am having some issues on how exactly to loop through the JavaRDD properly and set my rdd_value equal to the tuple's contained in rdd_array at whatever the b iterator counter value is.

Here is my code

```
//JavaRDD that contains Tuples
JavaRDD<Tuple5<Long, String, Float, Float, String>> rdd_array

//For loop to loop through rdd_array
for (int b=0;b<rdd_array.count();b++){

        //Need help on this line, how do I set rdd_row equal to the tuple5 in rdd_array
        Tuple5<Long, String, Float, Float, String> Value = rdd_array.;
        String id=Value._1().toString();
        String text=Value._2().toString();
        String negative_tweets=Value._3().toString();
        String positive_tweets=Value._4().toString();
        String score_tweets=Value._5().toString();
System.out.println(id+text+negative_tweets+positive_tweets+score_tweets)

}
```

Edit:
Guys, I am really trying here, took zero323 advice for a foreachloop on the JavaRDD receiving the error cannot resolve method.

```
rdd_array.foreach(new Function<Tuple5<Long, String, Float, Float, String>, Void>(){
            @Override
            public Void call(Tuple5<Long, String, Float, Float, String> rdd){
                String id=rdd._1().toString();
                String text=rdd._2().toString();
                String negative_tweets=rdd._3().toString();
                String positive_tweets=rdd._4().toString();
                String score_tweets=rdd._5().toString();

                System.out.println(id+text+negative_tweets+positive_tweets+score_tweets);
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I understand that RDD's are immutable.  All I am trying to do is read the tuples in the RDD and assign them to the variables you see in the code snippet.  Do I need to map over the RDD to a tuple to iterate over it?  How would one even go about doing any type of analysis on an RDD if it can't even be looped over.

Comment: Since your loop is used only for side effects `foreach` is probably what you want. Regarding your second question... Higher order functions are usually more than enough :)

Comment: @user2100493 users should not get automatically down voted on poor and honest first attempts, that is what this board is about. However traversing an RDD is at the very basics of Spark, and should be understood before a random attempt is made. If you do it incorrectly, you will never truly leverage the power of your multi node Spark cluster. See more in the [official spark guides](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#basics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your own attempt at an answer, you are actually dealing with something that looks like a `<K,V>`, with `K` (key) being Long, and `V` (value) a Tuple7. This is very different from what you presented in your original question. Most likely that can all be achieved more efficiently using a by a JavaPairRDD.

Starting from an RDD, you can convert an JavaRDD to a JavaPairRDD using

```
JavaPairRDD<Long,Tuple7<...>> prdd = rdd.mapToPair(...)
```

This will include a repartitioning based on your key.

Also doing your final processing using a `.foreach` will serialize your rdd results to your driver program and execute the contained logic serial. You might need to consider pushing most of your logic upstream of your RDD, using filter, reduce, and other paradigms. You can also consider using `.foreachPartition` to achieve some level of parallelism and compute on the task nodes rather than on the driver program.

Note that using Java 8 lambda syntax, you can write much of your logic more compact:

```
prdd.foreach((k,v)->{
  System.out.println("Printing: " + k + ", " + v._1() ...);
});
```

Now, to note another thing ... would it not be easier to use a more dedicated class instead of the generic `Tuple7<>`. In the very least it could look like something like this:

```
public class UserLocation {
  public long id;
  public String text;
  public String createdat;
  public String userlocation;
  public String name;
  public String username;
  public String lat;
  public String lon;
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return Long.toString(id)+text+createdat+userlocation+name+username+lat+lon;
  }
}
```

Then, your processing might look like something like this:

```
JavaRDD<UserLocation> jrdd;
JavaPairRDD<Long,UserLocation> jprdd = jrdd.mapToPair((v)->new Tupple2<>(v.id,v));
...

jprdd
  .foreach((k,v)->{
     System.out.println(v.toString());
  });
```

Ordinary, with this example, it serves no real purpose to map your data to a `JavaPairRDD<Long,UserLocation>`. However, your data will be repartitioned based on the Long key, and could have better parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using the following function

```
 rdd_array.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Long, Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Tuple2<Long, Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>> rdd_val) throws Exception {

            //new Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>(text,created_at,userlocation,name,username,lat,lon);
            String id = rdd_val._1().toString();
            String text = rdd_val._2()._1().toString();
            String createdat = rdd_val._2()._2().toString();
            String userlocation = rdd_val._2()._3().toString();
            String name = rdd_val._2()._4().toString();
            String username = rdd_val._2()._5().toString();
            String lat = rdd_val._2()._6().toString();
            String lon = rdd_val._2()._7().toString();


            System.out.println("Printing Values EXTRA: "+id+text+createdat+userlocation+name+username+lat+lon);
        }
    });
```